# Text and pictures when resizing windows html

Tags: html, css

On my website, I have two pictures 100 pixels off each side of the page. Underneath them I have text aligned 100 pixels off each side of the page. It looks great when the internet window is small. It looks like this:[Website Ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBjQ3.png)

But when I make the window larger it looks like this:[Website Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ESx1.png)

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

CSS:

```
.LG
{
    width: 20%;

}
#Garrett  {
    margin-left: 100px;
    float:left
}

#Luke {
    margin-right: 100px;
    float: right
}
#gname {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top:auto;
    float: left;
    font-family: Futura
}
#lname {
   float: right; 
    margin-right:100px;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-family: Futura
}
```

HTML:

```
   <img id=Garrett class=LG src="Screen%20Shot%202016-05-06%20at%204.58.49%20PM.png"/>
    <img id=Luke class=LG src="Screen%20Shot%202016-05-06%20at%205.01.11%20PM.png"/>
    <h4 id=gname>Garrett O'Connor</h4>
    <h4 id=lname>Luke Eder</h4>
```

Thanks

Comment: Bad HTML. Wrap `<img>` and  `<h4>` inside a `<div>`, both of them independently

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`float: left` and `float: right` are used to allow content to wrap around the floated elements. The problem is occurring when the screen is wider because there is room for the #Garrett and #Luke tags to `float` next to the `img` tags.

So the solution, as Marcos has suggested, is to wrap each group of content into a `div` like this:

```
<div class="left-box">
    <img id=Garrett class=LG src="Screen%20Shot%202016-05-06%20at%204.58.49%20PM.png"/>
    <h4 id=gname>Garrett O'Connor</h4>
</div>
<div class="right-box">
    <img id=Luke class=LG src="Screen%20Shot%202016-05-06%20at%205.01.11%20PM.png"/>
    <h4 id=lname>Luke Eder</h4>
</div>
```

Then you can add the CSS to the container `div` tags rather than to each individual element:

```
.left-box {
    margin-left: 100px;
    float:left
}
.right-box {
    margin-right: 100px;
    float:right
}
```

p.s. using figure and figcaption (as suggested by @C14L) would be the preferred method of wrapping the content as it is semantic. See here for more details http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you are happy that the answer is correct please mark as solved.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually HTML tags precisely for that case: `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`.

```
<figure class="one-pic">
  <img src="picture.png" alt="An awesome picture">  
  <figcaption>Foo Bar</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Then you can float the grouped element (picture plus caption) to the side of the viewscreen.

```
.one-pic {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

See [Mozilla docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure).

Comment: This is better, than my one. Using figure with fig caption is semantic.

Answer (score 1):

I've designed a small code for you.

This will help you out.

```
<div class="all-set"><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<ul><li class="left-box">
    <img id=Garrett class=LG src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/db85661fa6a6e059df0f053ce6cade50?s=80&d=https://codepen.io/assets/avatars/user-avatar-80x80-94696e1c3870f64217a8040eedd4a1ed.png"/>
    <h4 id=gname>Garrett O'Connor</h4>
</li>

<li class="right-box">
    <img id=Luke class=LG src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/db85661fa6a6e059df0f053ce6cade50?s=80&d=https://codepen.io/assets/avatars/user-avatar-80x80-94696e1c3870f64217a8040eedd4a1ed.png"/>
    <h4 id=lname>Luke Eder</h4>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/creativemind1/pen/PNVJyw

Well, if you can edit for your mobile, you can easily tweak it.
Check out how to use [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 1):

Here, I fixed your code, take a look at the updated code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jybqonpu/1/). I consolidated each side into its own div which I then floated to each side.

Careful with the way you're coding though - Don't use IDs for elements that don't need ids, surround classes and IDs with quotes like such:

```
<div class="lg"></div>
```

HTML is also designed for a hierarchy - if two elements are related to each other, then the HTML should reflect that, rather than relying solely on CSS. Things such as screen readers would be confused by anything less than that, and down the road, once you get farther with website dev, this is probably something you'd want to get out of the way.

Here's the new CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 15px;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 20%;
  font-family: Futura, Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.left img, .right img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

And the html: (Replace the img sources with your own images)

```
<div class="left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <h4>Garrett O'Connor</h4>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <h4>Luke Eder</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
p, h4 {  
  font-family: Futura;
  text-align: center;
}
div h4 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 4px;
}
div {  
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 140px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
#Garrett {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#Luke {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p><b>techniques used in business, and use only the finnest materials on the market.</b></p>
<div id="Garrett"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Garrett&w=100&h=100"/>
<h4>Garrett O'Connor</h4></div>
<div id="Luke">
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Luke&w=100&h=100"/>
<h4>Luke Eder</h4></div>
```